# Get length of a list javascript

Tags: javascript

When attempting to determine the length of a JavaScript list, I noticed that it returns the actual length of the list rather than the number of items within the string. Allow me to provide an example. Consider the following list:

```
<QuerySet [<Genre: Romance>, <Genre: Science Fiction>, <Genre: Fantasy>, <Genre: Mystery>, <Genre: Thriller>, <Genre: Horror>, <Genre: Historical Fiction>, <Genre: Biography>, <Genre: Autobiography>, <Genre: Memoir>, <Genre: Young Adult>, <Genre: Children's>, <Genre: Literary Fiction>, <Genre: Comedy>, <Genre: Business>, <Genre: Travel>, <Genre: Cookbooks>, <Genre: Poetry>, <Genre: Drama>, <Genre: Fairy-tail>]>
```

In my implementation, I retrieve the list as follows, where 'genres' represents the list:

```
<input type="hidden" id="genres_get" value="{{ genres }}" style="display: none;">
```

Getting it in Javascript

```
genres = document.getElementById('genres_get').value;
```

And trying to print the length

```
console.log(genres.length)
```

After executing the code, it incorrectly prints the value 414 instead of the expected length, which is 20.

Comment: That's right, it returns the actual length of the string, because property `value` can be only string type. There is a line about that [in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#value).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input's value is a string, not an array. If you put an array in the value, the array will be converted to string with .toString() which will join the elements with a comma. So when you do genres.length you are using the length property of a String and not an array, so you get the number of characters in the string.

You'd certainly want to split(',') the string and then count the elements.

```
console.log(genres.split(',').length)
```

Note that this is not really a good way to do it. Why are you putting the data in a hidden input in the first place? Can't you just hold onto it in your component?